# HashMap<Integer, String> stores String[] (Atlassian Confluence)

Tags: java, hashmap, confluence

So I'm working on a plugin for Atlassian Confluence and in my controller for the configuration page I have a HashMap of Type `HashMap<Integer, String>` that I fill with values from a HTML form. Now after submitting the form, I try to read a value from that HashMap with `.get(key)` and safe that to a String. I get this typecasting error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. So I looked at the values with a debugger and sure enough my HashMap contains strings wrapped in arrays of length 1 instead of plain simple strings: even tough my HashMap clearly is defined with types Integer->String and the assignment to String works without any explicit typecasting. This is really confusing me. I guess it has to do with the Atlassian stuff automagically deserializing POST-Values; in the past this has already cost me quite a lot of headaches, as there is no proper documentation and the magical background conversion has quite a lot of quirks. What really confuses me tough is the fact that the HashMap can suddenly store values of a different type than defined, I wouldn't have thought it possible with Java putting such a focus on type safety. Is there some reflection foo that can do this, that I'm unaware of? Or am I misunderstanding the nature of HashMaps? Anybody ever experienced something similar? I'm not that experienced at coding in Java.

Comment: *What really confuses me tough is the fact that the HashMap can suddenly store values of a different type than defined, I wouldn't have thought it possible with Java putting such a focus on type safety.* [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: For anybody struggling with Atlassian xwork/velocity forms, apparently the `field[1]` syntax for maps doesn't work. Maybe `field.1` would work, the dot-syntax works fine for nested objects (if you use @ParameterSafe on your classes). Arrays work in the form `<input name="test" value="A"><input name="test" value="B">` **instead of** `<input name="test[]" value="A"><input name="test[]" value="B">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are creating hashmap as `HashMap<Integer, String>()` but storing it as `HashMap` it is indeed possible to store there other types.

For example:

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, new String[]{"1", "2"});
    System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

This code executes without any errors.

So I think what happens is that in you are storing it just as a `HashMap` reference which is treated as `HashMap<Object, Object>` and as there is no runtime information about actual generic types you are able to add objects of other types to this collection.

But if you have another reference to the same map with `HashMap<Integer, String>` then when you call, for example, `get()`, it would fail with exception you described:

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, new String[]{"1", "2"});
    System.out.println(map.get(1));
    System.out.println("got here");
    HashMap<Integer, String> otherRef = (HashMap<Integer, String>) map;
    System.out.println(otherRef.get(1)); //<-ClassCastException exception here
```